# Mobile device type detection for styling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

Could anyone please advise on the best method to detect whether a site is being viewed on a mobile rather than a PC?  I would like to use a couple of mobile style sheets to suit each platform, but understand that iPhones/Android try to render the site as a PC rather than mobile?

I guess a JavaScript detection script may be an option?

Comment: possible duplicate of [detect mobile browser and javascript support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077080/detect-mobile-browser-and-javascript-support)

Comment: @MarcelKorpel: I may be wrong, but I think OP wants a straight-CSS solution, not intervening with JavaScript.

Comment: or rather: [How to Detect Mobile Browser Capability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428234/how-to-detect-mobile-browser-capability), as this is more something to do at the server side.

Comment: @Brad: you're right, I was too quick; however, there's a [javascript] tag in his question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [CSS @media](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)?

```
h2 {
  font-size: 12em;
}
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  h2 {
    font-size: 8em;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Emyr: Agreed, though I find it works /fairly well/ when the screen starts at a specific size range, and the problems /usually/ arise when on a resize event (though I could be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the use of @media may work for newer mobile devices and may be sufficient for your needs. [I found this article to be very helpful for iPhone mobile website development.](http://csswizardry.com/2010/01/iphone-css-tips-for-building-iphone-websites/)

If you need to do quality mobile detection on the server then you will need to get the server-side developers involved. I use the [Wurfl database](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) in order to power our mobile detection on the server, which then directs the inclusion or exclusion of various stylesheets, scripts, and even some page workflows.